# How to avoid duplicates when adding items to a list box in C#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I have a list boxes `List1` and `List2` and I want to add selected item from `List2` to `List1`. I do as follows.

```
List1.Items.Add(List2.SelectedItem);
```

How to avoid duplicating in `List1` if the same item from `List2` is being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (List2.SelectedItem != null 
  if (! List1.Items.Contains(List2.SelectedItem))
     {  List1.Items.Add(List2.SelectedItem);
        List2.Remove(List2.SelectedItem);
     }
```